# how to implement attributes of iframe to the window only after opening not in the iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

how to implement attributes of iframe to the window only after opening not in the iframe.

I have iframe tag like  this.

```
<div className="w-6 h-4 ">

      <iframe

        src="https://mydomin/app"

        allow="microphone"
        className="bg-white"
        height={"100%"}
        width="100%"

      />

    </div>
```

so as you can see here in iframe i am using allow attribute. But I don't want to do that in tag. As the window get open in new domian there I want to set allow, Is there any way instead of passing to tag I can set this mydomin/app/. I have codebase access of mydomian/app.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by code vs tag? Are you using some framework? I noticed the height={"100%"}, can you not set a variable and src={src}? Unless I have misunderstood

Comment: Do you understand what the `allow` attribute does? Here it's like you're trapped in a cage and you're asking for a way to open the cage from the inside.

Comment: @Kaiido yes. " The policy defines what features are available to the <iframe> based on the origin of the request. " I don't have access of codebase from where the iframe is coming from, therefore i can not write `allow` attaribute there, thats why I need in my app

Comment: `allow={allowAttributes}` and then you can set `allowAttributes` in whatever framework it looks like you're using

Comment: I'm sure that you don't think of yourself as dangerous, but take a step back. Would you want any website you embed in an iframe on which you said they aren't allowed to do something to be able to do it anyway? That's what you're asking for.

Comment: @Kaiido I am asking if I can set allow attribute to the website which is embded, once it is loaded. The website which i am loading that is mine only.

Comment: @Dale so I need to pass allowAttribute from the iframe tag. I wanted to avoid to pass `allow` from iframe.